# Netstream Pause/Unpause Notify will never fire when play video through HTTP

Tags: actionscript-3, playback, netstream, video-player

This is so strange that I have no idea how to search it specifically. I googled it and there seems to be that someone has already asked this but no solution replied.
The video file is on the server, say, http: //xxx.com/xxx.flv, and I play it using Video & NetStream. Here's the code(assume that all the varibles have been defined):

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.inBufferSeek = true;
ns.play("http: //xxx.com/xxx.flv");
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,statusControl);
function statusControl(e:NetStatusEvent){
     trace(e.info.code);
}
```

According to the [doc](http://help.adobe.com/zh_CN/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info), I should get a "NetStream.Pause.Notify" when I call `ns.pause()`, truth is, that never happened.
So here I am. ANYONE ANY IDEA?

EDIT: Because of the FLVPlayback thing I met before, I try to find how the different Flash Player versions affect. And I think that I found something, if I publish it for FP 10/10.1/10.2, it will not dispatch `Netstream.Pause/Unpause.Notify`, but the ones for 10.3+ work fine. The problem is that I really need to publish it for FP 10 & 10.1, the videos my company converted seem to act nicely only with FP 10 & 10.1, and I can't change that. Wait for help~

Answer (score 0):

`ns.pause()` doesn't work reliably to listen for when the video is not playing anymore. Try listening for `ns.stop()` instead as it has the same basic functionality.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked, and actually there's no such method `ns.stop()`. I guess that you're trying to say "NetStream.Play.Stop", I don't think this is what I want. "NetStream.Play.Stop" dispatches when the video reaches the end, but I need to detect when the video is paused/unpaused.